# How to decrypt a file to a temporary one, and read it without saving?

Tags: encryption, openssl

say this:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -in test.txt -out test-enc.txt
```

Then

```
rm test.txt
```

Then, I'd like do decrypt text-enc.txt without saving the output, just see it on a text editor (say sublime text) and then close and forget. So on my disc there's only test-enc.txt. Is it possible?

If possible, I'd like to save some aliases on my bashrc to open, modify and encrypt it again.

Comment: You might want to consider a purpose-built program for saving encrypted text (like a password manager, KeePass, etc) that won't scatter temporary files around your hard drive, and other (editing) programs that use your decrypted file might write more temporary files too, it's trivial to undelete a file that's only been `rm`'d, and if your swap isn't encrypted it could be another leak. And openssl's `enc` command [might not be particularly secure on it's own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28248800/3412074)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `/dev/shm`, which is usually populated with a `tmpfs` which resides in memory only. Another way would be to use pipes for transferring the data from `openssl ... -out /dev/stdout` to the desired program using pipes and stdin.

Comment: tmpfs may be written out to swap, while ramfs isn't (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt)

Comment: Thank you for that interesting detail, which is new for me.